# Combining 2 Array into dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I want to combine 2 array.

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
arr2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

i want to make it to be :

```
"a" = "1"
"b" = "2"
"c" = "3"
```

so if i call value "1" into label1, it means value "a" is also called into label2 just like dictionary or index.

Comment: what if array size is different?

Comment: Try This Code:-

let arr1 = ["1","2","3"]
let arr2 = ["A","B","C"]
let combinedDict = NSMutableDictionary()
        
        for i in 0..<arr1.count{
            
            combinedDict.addEntries(from: [arr2[i] : arr1[i]])
        }
        print(combinedDict)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like that:

```
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
let arr2 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's one line code

```
let dict = zip(["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]).compactMap{[$0.0:$0.1]}.reduce([:]) { $0.merging($1) { (current, _) in current } }       
print(dict)
```

> ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"]

I suggests you to use **user28434**'s answer which is more effective than mine. I am keeping my answer as alternative second best solution